# Simple example of changing a textView in a Fragment from an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone please code a simple example for me, on how to change the contents of a TextView inside a Fragment from an Activity (eg. MainActivity.java)?

I have tried this several times and my app crashes every time.
I tried to use the methods I create.
There's no point by complicating the question by posting my erroneous code.

Comment: Can you put some key code?

Comment: Googling was worth trying. However refer this [Official Doc Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use interfaces to communicate between activity and fragment

This interface will notify your fragment to update with the data in the bundle

```
public interface UpdateFragmentInterface {
    public void update(Bundle data);
}
```

This interface is used in the activity to be notified when a fragment has attached

```
public interface OnUpdatableFragmentAttached {

    public void onAttach(UpdateFragmentInterface iFace);
    public void onDetach(UpdateFragmentInterface iFace);

}
```

Some dummy activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class UpdatableActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnUpdatableFragmentAttached {

    private ArrayList<UpdateFragmentInterface> listOfUpdatableFragments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Do other stuff
        listOfUpdatableFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void notifyFragments(){
        String someString = "asda";
        String someKey = "key1234";
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(someKey, someString);

        for(UpdateFragmentInterface fragment : listOfUpdatableFragments){
            fragment.update(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(UpdateFragmentInterface iFace) {
        listOfUpdatableFragments.add(iFace);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(UpdateFragmentInterface iFace) {
        listOfUpdatableFragments.remove(iFace);
    }

}
```

And some dummy fragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    public class UpdatableFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateFragmentInterface {

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            if(activity instanceof OnUpdatableFragmentAttached){
                ((OnUpdatableFragmentAttached) activity).onAttach(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            if(getActivity() instanceof OnUpdatableFragmentAttached){
                ((OnUpdatableFragmentAttached) getActivity()).onDetach(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Bundle data) {
            // Do something with the data
            String result = data.getString("key1234");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743862/updating-a-textview-s-in-a-fragment-from-an-activity-using-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use an Event Bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).

```
public enum SingletonBus {
    INSTANCE;

    private Bus bus;

    private SingletonBus() {
        this.bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    public Bus getBus() {
        return bus;
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
          //do whatever
     }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
          SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
          super.onPause();
     }

     @Override
     public void onPostResume() { //using this to send event only for sake of example
         SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().post(new TextViewChangeEvent("hello world!"));
     }
}
```

and

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
     @InjectView(R.id.your_text_view)
     public TextView yourTextView;


     @Override
     public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
          ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
          //do whatever
          return view;
     }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
          SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
          super.onPause();
     }

     @Subscribe
     public void onTextViewChangeEvent(TextViewChangeEvent e) {
          this.yourTextView.setText(e.getText());
     }
}
```

with

```
public class TextViewChangeEvent {
     private String text;

     public TextViewChangeEvent(String text) {
          this.text = text;
     }

     public String getText() {
          return text;
     }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743862/updating-a-textview-s-in-a-fragment-from-an-activity-using-viewpager